# how to generate html and css file dynamically using javascript for download by the user from string?

Tags: javascript

I have a css code and html code in a string and want to create a .html and .css file for download. Is it actually possible?

I've used this example but it prints all code exactly as string and not as real css/html code

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow ok, I found the solution. Just remove first and last quotations. tada...

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var parsed = data.replace(/^['"].*['"]+/g, ''),
            blob = new Blob([parsed], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cW7W5/1356/